# Javascript insertion sort bug

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've been trying to convert my python code into javascript. Basically it's a insertion sort that also sorts a secondary list of the same size with arbitrary values relative to the first list.

i.e. a = [3,2,1] and b = [c,b,a] will return [1,2,3] and [a,b,c] for a and b.

Here's my code:

```
function insertionSort(alist,bList){
    for (index=1;index<alist.length;index++){
        var currentvalue = alist[index]
        var currentvalue2 = blist[index]
        var position = index
    }
    while (position>0 && alist[position-1]>currentvalue){
        alist[position]=alist[position-1]
        blist[position]=blist[position-1]
        position = position-1
    }
    alist[position]=currentvalue
    blist[position]=currentvalue2
}
```

Works fine in python, but not at all here. What have I done?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Check `{` `}` . It seems `for` loop is doing nothing. And `while` should be inside `for` loop.

Comment: Yup, that did it, I put the } too high up when converting. Should be after blist[position]=currentvalue2.

Works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but I think it have to be:

```
function insertionSort(alist,bList){
    for (index=1;index<alist.length;index++){
        var currentvalue = alist[index]
        var currentvalue2 = blist[index]
        var position = index

        while (position>0 && alist[position-1]>currentvalue){
            alist[position]=alist[position-1]
            blist[position]=blist[position-1]
            position = position-1
        }

        alist[position]=currentvalue
        blist[position]=currentvalue2
    }
}
```